# Image is not rendering when i creating android app

Tags: react-native

when i run the code image is not rendering on the screen. please see the bellow code .

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <View style={Styles.conatiner} >
            <View style={Styles.first_part}>
                <View style={Styles.first_part_1}>
                    <Image
                        resizeMethod="resize"
                        onError={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.error)}
                        source={require("./assets/images/Vector 28.png")}
                        style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} />
                    <View style={Styles.first_part_1a}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontFamily: "Montserrat-Bold", color: "black" }}> Signalier un proobleme</Text></View>
                </View>
            </View>
            <View style={Styles.second_part}>
                <View style={Styles.second_partA}>
                    <View style={Styles.second_part_1}>
                        <Text style={Styles.second_part_1a}> Per default</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={Styles.second_text_1}>
                        <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 11, fontFamily: "Montserrat-Medium" }}> Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet </Text>
                        <RadioBtn style={{ marginLeft: scale(120) }} />
                    </View>
                     <View style={Styles.second_text_1a}>
                        <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 11, fontFamily: "Montserrat-Medium" }}> Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet </Text>
                        <RadioBtn style={{ marginLeft: scale(120) }} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={Styles.second_text_1b}>
                        <Text style={{ color: "black", fontSize: 11, fontFamily: "Montserrat-Medium" }}> Lorem Ipsum dolar sit amet lorem </Text>
                        <RadioBtn style={{ marginLeft: scale(87) }} />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <TextInput style={Styles.third_part} />
                <View style={Styles.fourth}>
                    <Btn title={"press me"} onPress={HandleButton} /></View>
                </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: You use tool to convert html to react-native? Because i see 2 error in your code that are ignoreable errors in html.

Comment: Line 3: `<View style={Styles.conatiner} >` typo?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with your image name

```
source={require("./assets/images/Vector 28.png")}
```

There is a space in image name which may be reason to not show the images.
Please change the image file name without space like `Vector28.png` and try passing image source like this

```
source={require("./assets/images/Vector28.png")}
```

There is an old reported issue in react native but it seems fixed : [Can't require image with spaces, etc. in filename](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10364)